# Apply "Individual Quota" to site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there any way to reverting back to individual Quota if site collection using quota template using Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using the below code

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication "Replace it with Web App URL"

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{
    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        $Site = Get-SPSite -Identity $SPSite.url        
        $Site.Quota = $null                                 
        $Site.Dispose()       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://portal

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{
    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        Set-SPSite -Identity $SPSite.url -QuotaTemplate "12345678-90ab-cdef-1234-567890abcdef"
        $SPSite.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this, It is working if i am applying Some quota Template..

Comment: But not working if i need to Apply "No Quota"

Comment: @Atul What happens if you run `Remove-SPQuotaTemplate -Name "Custom"`

Comment: Error "Not a Valid Command"  To explain i have a site collection with "Personnal Quota" Template applied.                                                    Now, I want to replace it back to Individual Quota "Default" I can do it in central admin But looking for a PS script if it is achievable.